# Proper way to pass QColor object into Qdialog subclass

Tags: qt, c++11

I am having a problem with a QDialog subclass that I am using to pass two QT Objects into: QColor and QFont. If I pass by reference the application unexpectedly crashes before it can run even though it compiled out without error.

I was able to get it to work using pointers but it looks ugly, and messes up the rest of the code. I want to get it working by reference and refrain from using 'New' keyword to instantiate QFont or QColor classes. So basically my working subclass constructer using pointers looks like this:

> HEADER:
>
> ```
> class MySettingsDialog : public QDialog
> {
> Q_OBJECT
>
> public:
> explicit MySettingsDialog(QColor *acolor, QFont *afont, QWidget *parent=0);
>
> CLASS FILE:
> MySettingsDialog::MySettingsDialog(QColor *acolor, QFont *afont, QWidget *parent) :
> QDialog(parent, Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint), m_color(*acolor),     m_font(*afont),
> ui(new Ui::MySettingsDialog)
> {
>
> ui->setupUi(this);
> }
> ```

This way works but I have to in my MainWindow.cpp file declare for example:

> QFont * systemFont;
>
> ```
>  systemFont = New QFont("myfont whatever");
> ```

And everywhere I want to apply that font I have to unmask like this:
ui->mylabel->setfont(*systemFont).

Before I wasn't using 'new' to instantiate my systemFont variable and systemFont wasn't declared as a pointer in the header file. Such that if Mydialog was declared like this the program crashes:

DOESNT WORK:

> HEADER
>
> ```
>  explicit MySettingsDialog(const QColor &acolor, const QFont &afont, QWidget *parent=0);
>
> CLASS FILE:
>  MySettingsDialog::MySettingsDialog(const QColor &acolor, const QFont &afont, QWidget      *parent) :
>  QDialog(parent, Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint), m_color(acolor), m_font(afont),
>  ui(new Ui::MySettingsDialog)
> {
>
> ui->setupUi(this);
>  }
> ```

Mainwindow:

> MySettingsDialog(systemColor, systemFont, this);

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: don't abuse pointers. use `QFont systemFont;` `ui->mylabel->setfont(systemFont).`

Answer (score 0):

Things got stranger and stranger but I finally figured it out. It seems as if you can't instantiate a `QDialog` subclass within a function subroutine. I had an `init()` routine and running this code not work:

> void MyProgram::init() {
> systemColor =  QColor("red");
> systemFont = QFont("Consolas", zoomFactor);
>
> ```
> settingsDialog = new UefiSettingsDialog(systemColor, systemFont, this);
> ......  ...  ...  }
> ```

but the same code called right at the beginning of the start of code works without any failure to launch. Probably a scope issue though I have no idea why.